# Visual Studio 2010- images in ImageList quality drop on every compilation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, imagelist

I use original VS 2010, so it's not problem with some "crack stuff" etc.

On every compilation of my program (Winforms, C# if that matters) quality of images stored in `ImageList` drops a little. After 20-30 compilations it looks very bad.

Removing all images and readding them is only way I know. `ImageList's` ColorDepth is set to 32.

- **Left:** how it should look like (first compilation after readding images)
- **Right:** how it looks like after about 30 compilations.

[image]

Do You have any idea how to fix that? It's really frustrating when I have to readd all images  before almost every release.

Comment: what format are the images?

Comment: What type of compression are You using? What format? PNG? JPEG? BMP? Try to search in VS2010 options for images and set in image properties, the action for image: `resource`.

Comment: I use pngs. (blahblah- post length)

Comment: I have the same problem. We are in 2020 and the problem remains. I can't belive that Microsoft didn't pay attention to this bug, simply amazing.